# Factory method isn't getting called correctly in Spring

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services

I am trying to create an SNS client bean.

```
<bean id="snsClientBuilder" class="com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClientBuilder"
          factory-method="standard">
        <property name="credentials" ref="credntialsPair" />
        <property name="region" value="us-west-2" />
    </bean>

<bean id="snsClient" factory-bean="snsClientBuilder" factory-method="build"/>
/>
```

Code

```
    @Autowired
    private AmazonSNSClientBuilder snsClientBuilder;

    @Autowired
    private AmazonSNS snsClient;

    @Autowired
    private String notificationTopicArn; //Bean also correctly defined

     @Override
    public void sendNotification(final Notification notification) {
        final String message = notification.toJson();

         //wrapped in a try catch
         snsClient.publish(new PublishRequest().withMessage(message).withTopicArn(notificationTopicArn));
    }
```

This sns call fails with error

```
Invalid parameter: TopicArn (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: f320367c-774d-55c0-8b1b-609005851d6c)
```

I know the problem is that the sns client has the wrong region, because if i do this.

```
@Override
    public void sendNotification(final Notification notification) {
        final String message = notification.toJson();

        //works, but i dont want to set the region everytime
        snsClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
         //wrapped in a try catch
         snsClient.publish(new PublishRequest().withMessage(message).withTopicArn(notificationTopicArn));
    }
```

It works. Also if i do this.

```
@Override
    public void sendNotification(final Notification notification) {
        final String message = notification.toJson();

       //works, but i want this built as a bean
        snsClient = snsClientBuilder.build()
         //wrapped in a try catch
         snsClient.publish(new PublishRequest().withMessage(message).withTopicArn(notificationTopicArn));
    }
```

Looks like this line `<bean id="snsClient" factory-bean="snsClientBuilder" factory-method="build"/>` just doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Do not use the old xml based configuration, use the modern annotation based way

Comment: Not my decision to make. Do you know why the old way isn't working in this case?